# Automatic Deserialising nested json in POST - Jersery + Jackson - Missing class indicator field from database row

Tags: rest, post, jackson, jersey, jackson-databind

I have POST method that looks something Like this

```html
    POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/newJob")
    public JobResponseDTO addNewJob(JobDataDTO jobDataDTO) {
```

JobDataDTO looks like this

```html
    public String jobName;

    public JsonNode info;

    public String jobType;
```

The info property contains nested json which has no defined structure.

I am using Jersey and Jackson.

Whenever I am passing a json as following:-

```html
{
    "jobName": "MysqlJob",
    "jobType": "Mysql",
    "info:   : {
      "key"    : "xyz",
      "params" : {
          "resource": "item",
           "request_id": "c0f2befd-540e-44f9-84b5-9094be40b983",
           "date": "2018-11-30 PST;2018-12-16 PST",
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting exceptions.

```html
avax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception [EclipseLink-44] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException|Exception Description: Missing class indicator field from database row [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl@1b1bfcec].|Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode --> [])
```

Alot stuck at this.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Jackson as the JSON Provider? What server are you using?

Comment: I am using Jetty Server . but what it has to do with server?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work in following manner.

Adding @JsonCreator attribute on constructor of JobDataDTO and declaring @JsonProperty in args of constructor.

````
@JsonCreator
public JobDataDTO(@JsonProperty("info") JsonNode info, String jobName, String jobType)```
````